# place UISegmentedControl in thenavigation bar of a View of a TabBarController(implemented through code)

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

How to place a uisegmentedcontrol in the navigation bar of a view of a tabbarcontroller which is implemented through code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller:

```
NSArray *items = NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Option"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:array] autorelease];
```